# fetching binary files from Access via ODBC in PHP only returns first 4 KB

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to use PHP (CodeIgniter) and ODBC to fetch files (image, pdf, doc) stored in an Access database and show them in a browser. Unfortunately it returns only the first 4kb of every file.

```
$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->query("select  noe,file from Sanad_File
where id=$id");
$rowim=$query->result();
if($rowim[0]->noe=="pdf")
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
else if ($rowim[0]->noe=="jpg") 
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
else if ($rowim[0]->noe=="tif") 
header('Content-Type: image/tiff');
else if ($rowim[0]->noe=="doc" || $rowim[0]->noe=="docx")   
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
echo $rowim[0]->file;
```

I suspect that it's an ODBC issue. Can anyone help me find the solution?

Comment: You may want to check your php.ini file to see if there is a max upload limit.

Comment: tanx for comment.I'll test your suggest, but I did not any upload in this code.

Comment: Ah I see, its probably not a good idea to store files in a database, it would be better to store the link to the file, and have the file stored external to the db.

Comment: yes, I am agree with you. but I am working on a database that created before.I do not store files in this manner in my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for `longreadlen` is 4096 (ref: [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-binmode.php)). You will need to increase that value via [`odbc_longreadlen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-longreadlen.php).